# Can I use Secure Boot on my dualboot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

So I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 2004. I tried to install Ubuntu a few months ago when I had a MBR disk . After installing, GRUB gave me a `grub rescue<` error and I fixed it by running Boot Repair.

I switched to GPT and UEFI and a clean installation of Windows 10(Secure Boot is on). Will Secure Boot affect my dualboot and is it even worth it to use Secure Boot?

Info:

- Dell Latitude E6430

  Intel Core i5-3320M

  Intel HD 4000 Graphics

  Intel Centrino Wi-Fi Card

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please ask one question at a time. Questions with opinion based answers are off-topic. What is worth to someone depends on that someone.

Comment: In the future we may need/want Secure Boot. Torvalds clarifies Linux's Windows 8 Secure Boot position
http://www.zdnet.com/torvalds-clarifies-linuxs-windows-8-secure-boot-position-7000011918/
 the whole UEFI thing is more about control than security